# Creating SSIS package in VS2013 for SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools, bids

Our IT department bought `SQL Server 2012 Enterprise` and `VS 2013 Pro` many years ago.

I realize that `SQL Server 2012 Agent` will not execute SSIS packages created in `VS2013`. So what are my options, if any?

Is there any way I can create SSIS packages in VS2013 that will run in SQL Server 2012?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of SSDT is free, and supports SSIS versions 2012 and later.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt

Comment: By installing VS2015 and SSDT 2015, would I be able to create packages that target sql server 2012? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. By installing VS2015 and SSDT 2015, you would be able to create packages that target SQL Server 2012